# What is the grey Indicator in Unit Test Case

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

When using `XCTExpectFailure` and run the test cases (<kbd>Cmd + U</kbd>) From "Show the Test navigator" it show's grey cross (x) Other test cases shows in green Colour.

What is the Grey Indicator (x) In Test Cases ?

[image]

Do need to do anything here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode has four indicators for the result of a test.

#### Green Tick – The test passed

[image: screenshot of the green tick test passed indicator in Xcode]

#### Red Cross – The test failed

[image: screenshot of the red cross test failure indicator in Xcode2]

#### Gray Cross – The test failed, but it was expected to

[image: screenshot of the gray cross test failed as expected indicator in Xcode]

Xcode will show you this only if you already declared that a test was *expected to fail* using the [`XCTExpectFailure`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/3726077-xctexpectfailure) API.

It's Xcode way to tell you "hey this test failed but I'm not going to report it as a failure because you told me it was expected." This is useful to avoid blocking a build in CI if because when there's an expected failure.

I would encourage you to use `XCTExpectFailure` parsimoniously. It's useful to avoid being blocked by a test failure that is unrelated to your work, but you should always take the time to go back and fix the failure, don't leave the `XCTExpectFailure` call in your test suite for long.

#### Gray Arrow – The test was skipped

[image: screenshot of the gray arrow test skipped indicator in Xcode]

Xcode will show this when a test was skipped using [`XCTSkipIf`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/3521325-xctskipif) or [`XCTSkipUnless`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/3521326-xctskipunless).

Similarly to an expected failure, you don't *need* to do anything about this because either you or someone else in your team added the API call to skip the test, meaning the behavior is expected. It's useful to skip tests if they depend on certain runtime capabilities that might not be available on the device or Simulator executing a test run.

Answer (score 0):

Grey sign appears when test is run successfully and u can click on it to check the performance results in left bar